# Pythonic way to remove specific characters from a string

Tags: python

I want to remove specific characters from a string. I am using the following code:

```py
words = words.replace("[", "").replace("_", "").replace("[","").replace("]", "")\
.replace("(", "").replace("/", "")
```

This code works fine but it is a bit messy. I am wondering if there is a better way to do this?

Comment: Use `re.sub()` with a regexp that matches all the characters you want to remove.

Comment: if you have a different criterion for substitution then you can check `str.translate`

Comment: also words = words.translate({ord(c):None for c in "[(_/)]"})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `re.sub` with a character class containing the individual characters you want to remove:

```py
words = re.sub(r'[\[\]_(/]', '', words)
```